# How to use ternary operator to render jsx using react and javscript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have code like below,

```
{hideValue && !isOpen && (
    <span>
      {percentage}
    </span>
  )}
  {!hideValue && !isOpen && (
    <span>
      {value}
    </span>
  )}
```

how to rewrite above code using ternary operator?

I am new to ternary operator usage. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Why? Whats wrong with what you have? In any case what do you want to happen when `hideValues && isOpen` or `!hideValues && isOpen` (ie you have 2 cases currently not covered)?

Comment: Ternary operator is [very simple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). If condition is true, first part is asserted, if not, the second part. That's all there is to it. In your case `{ condition ? (<jsx-for-true />) : (<jsx-for-false />) }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you have it's ok (maybe there's some duplicated code), but you can indeed use a ternary operator.

A ternary operator is basically a shorthand way of writing an if-else statement. In this case, if `hideValue` is `true` we want to show `percentage` otherwise we show `value`.

Something like this:

```
{!isOpen && 
  (hideValue ? <span>{percentage}</span> : <span>{value}</span>
)}
```

Note that since `!isOpen` always needs to be false you can very it before.

You can additionally implement it like this:

```
{!isOpen && <span> {hideValue ? percentage : value} </span>}
```

since they both use the `<span>` tag.